# npm install fails with 'Object for dependency is empty' error in ag-viewer setup script

Tags: npm, apache-age

I want to setup the apache-age viewer with npm but when i execute the command `npm run setup` it gives me the following error.

```
> ag-viewer@0.0.1 setup-front /home/Desktop/age-viewer
> cd frontend && npm install

npm WARN read-shrinkwrap This version of npm is compatible with lockfileVersion@1, but package-lock.json was generated for lockfileVersion@2. I'll try to do my best with it!
npm ERR! Object for dependency "globals" is empty.
npm ERR! Something went wrong. Regenerate the package-lock.json with "npm install".
npm ERR! If using a shrinkwrap, regenerate with "npm shrinkwrap".

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/.npm/_logs/2023-05-04T09_33_17_778Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! ag-viewer@0.0.1 setup-front: `cd frontend && npm install`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the ag-viewer@0.0.1 setup-front script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/.npm/_logs/2023-05-04T09_33_17_843Z-debug.log
ERROR: "setup-front" exited with 1.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! ag-viewer@0.0.1 setup: `npm install && npm-run-all setup-front setup-backend`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the ag-viewer@0.0.1 setup script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/.npm/_logs/2023-05-04T09_33_17_911Z-debug.log
```

Can anyone provide guidance on what might be going wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message indicates that there was a problem with the npm install command inside the setup-front script of the ag-viewer project. The error specifically means that there is already 'package-lock.json' and you need to regenerate it. Try the following command to solve the issue

```
cd /home/Desktop/age-viewer/frontend
rm package-lock.json
npm install
```

Once you remove it now when you run the `npm run setup` it will solve the issue.

Comment: Yea you are right, removing the package-lock.json file actually solved the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try deleting package-lock and the node modules (if the folder exists) and try again

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a problem with the **npm** command. So, try running:

```
npm cache clean --force
npm install
npm run setup
```

If the above doesn't work, you can do this manually by deleting the `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` file and run `npm run setup` again.

Make sure that you have latest version of **npm** installed.

```
npm install -g npm
```

Answer (score 0):

Open your terminal and navigate to your project directory using "cd" command.
Run this command

`'rm -rf node_modules'`  to remove node_modules folder.

Now run this command `npm install` to reinstall node_modules

If error came again then try running `npm cache clean --force`

If again error then share your snapshot of logs at /home/.npm/_logs/

Answer (score 0):

You can just remove the `package-lock.json` file and run again the `npm -i` command

Answer (score 0):

delete node module file and .lockjson file then run these commands in terminal hopefully this will resolve your issue

```
npm cache clean --force
npm install
npm run setup
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems that the error has occurred due to an issue with the npm install command.
Try following these steps:
Navigate to the front end directory of the age-viewer project:

```
cd /home/Desktop/age-viewer/frontend
```

Path may vary depending upon actual location on your device.

Next delete the `package-lock.json` file:

```
rm package-lock.json
```

Then, install the dependencies of project again using the command `npm install`

Now go back to the root directory of your project

```
cd /home/Desktop/age-viewer
```

This path can also vary depending on where the project is installed.

Finally run the command

```
 npm run setup
```

Hopefully it will resolve the issue.